# How to include Logo in Reset password email in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I am trying to customize reset password blade.

So far,

I have put this code in User.php model.

```
public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token)
{
    $this->notify(new ResetPasswordNotification($token));
}
```

And,

php artisan make:notification MyOwnResetPassword
I used this command to publish custom notification

```
public function toMail($notifiable)
{

    return (new MailMessage)
                ->subject('Reset Password')
                ->line('You are receiving this email because we received a password reset request for your account.')
                ->action('Reset Password', url('admin/password/reset/'.$this->token, false))
                ->line('If you did not request a password reset, no further action is required.');
}
```

The question is how to add a Logo?

Any help or reference would be great

Thanks

Comment: Using `line` method you can display image logo. Also change `{{` to `{!!` in template

Comment: thnx.. I got the solution,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the documentation (https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/notifications#mail-notifications) It says that your new MailMessage is sending a formatted message.

Also you can customize your template :

> in the resources/views/vendor/notifications directory

You probably need to run that command before : `php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-notifications`

You can see all the documentation here : https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/notifications#customizing-the-templates

Comment: Thank you so much. I found it.